# Firebase Auth SMS does not contain an 11-characters hash

Tags: firebase-authentication

Im trying to use Firebase Auth for Phone authentication, everything is setup and im receiving an SMS on my app, but it doesnt contain an 11-characters hash at the bottom of the sms body, hence why i cannot use the auto retrieval feature.
I set up my SHA-1 & SHA-256 and everything, but what im getting is a URL to my firebase project instead of the hash code.

Is there anything im doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @PratikButani not really

Comment: same problem with me. I have already some apps that receive 11 char hash but I don't know why it's not receiving in my older app which I am recently updating.